# Forward Model Selection Using p-value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, modeling, p-value, feature-selection, model-selection

I know that it is not advised to use the p-value as the criterion in practice, but I am **not** asking about that. I am wondering how this p-value would actually be calculated. In other words:

Forward selection starts with no parameters, then tests each parameter individually. The parameter with the smallest (read: most significant) p-value that is below the significance level is chosen to be added. Then this process repeats until no parameters are below the significance level.

This all makes sense to me, except for the explicit computation of the p-value. From what I can tell: Our $H_0$ is "all parameters are equal to 0" and our $H_{\textrm{alt},i}$ is "parameter $i$ is nonzero." Then we calculate the p-value by finding the probability under $H_0$ that data is observed that is as rare or more rare than actually observed. But then it appears that each test ($\forall i$) will have the same p-value, because it's based on $H_0$, which is the same. Therefore the p-values for all possible parameters will be the same, and we do not have a smallest one to choose. Can someone please clear this up for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The $p$ value is not only a function of the hypotheses you want to test, but also depends on the test statistic. In the case of a multiple regression, it depends on the parameter estimates (and the standard errors, and the degrees of freedom), so if the parameter estimates are different, so will be the $p$ values.